# Do both websites and networks have ip addresses

Tags: ip-address

So to my understanding, each network has its own IP Address and each device on the network has the same IP Address (externally). Do websites also have IP Addresses as well because I know that websites have their own IP Addresses? How can two completely different things share the same identification method?

Thanks

Comment: Network's don't have an IP address, they have an IP address _range_ or subnet. Each device on the network has its own IP address (local to the network). The firewall/router that connects a local network to the public Internet will usually have a public IP address (but theoretically it could also have multiple), and it would use NAT (network address translation) to ensure the proper routing of the packets. It would then appear to the outside as if all the devices had the same IP address.

Comment: A website also has an IP address (or many). A website's DNS record has to (eventually) resolve to an IP address. It would be the public IP address of the server (or the first endpoint in a "chain" or servers, for example a firewall or a content delivery network endpoint) that serves the website. Just like with your home network, the servers will probably also have additional local IP addresses that are valid in their internal networks only.

Comment: Ok, so they both use the same concept of IP Addresses? But why?

Comment: Because an IP address is just a way to identify a node in a network. A website, or actually a server serving a website, is just another node in a network (in the big network called "Internet").

Comment: And the network itself doesn't have an address. It has a range of addresses which are per se only valid inside the network itself. You need a router to route packets between different networks. Your home router for example will have two IP addresses: A public one 11.22.33.44 that is known to the Internet, and a private one 10.0.0.1 that is known to your home network only (which may use the range 10.0.0.X for its nodes). From that perspective, you may think that your home network has IP 11.22.33.44 but that's not true, your _router_ has this IP address (towards the Internet).